# How to find the index of a struct in an array c#

Tags: c#

Using the struct below, if I had an array of type `Member` how would I go about finding the index of a `Member` in that array if I knew the name without using LINQ?

```
struct Member 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: why don't you show us what you have tried on your own, doesn't appear that you've done any research what soever on your own. This is not a `Code it for me please Site`

Comment: Yes it is possible @Im Arron, check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9hy2xwa(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If the id is unique, you should consider using a `Dictionary`.  Otherwise you can simply loop through the array until you find the desired element or call linq's `First()` or one of the better answers below :)

Comment: If you want to find index use members.Select((x,i) new {member = x, index = i}).Where(x => x.member.id = 1234).ToList()

Comment: In hindsight, this was a poorly worded question. I hope my edits make it a much more useful question, even if it was written 2 and a bit years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, and you don't even have to use LINQ :)

```
Array.FindIndex(yourarray, s => s.name == "John")
```

The return value from this method call is the first index of your array where the array element ( referred to as `s` ) has a name equal to John

findIndex can also take additional parameters to start searching part way through etc, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03y7c6xy(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit:

I thought you'd asked for the array index, but it seems you want the related ID given the name.

No problem, just use the Array.Find method in the same way. Instead of returning you the index of the array where the found name was, it will return you the first struct with that name, and you can then get the ID from it

```
Array.Find(yourarray, s => s.name == "John") //returns the matching struct
```

Note that if there is no matching name, you'll get struct representing the default(T) back. You should also note that if you plan to manipulate the struct you get back, it WON'T change the values of the struct in the array (Find returns you a copy of the array entry). In that case, use FindIndex and then manipulate the array entry via something like `yourarray[foundindex].name = "Jon"`

Comment: What you've posted is working for me to an extent - I now want to change `s.name == "John"` to `s.id == 56` but when trying to do int.Parse I receive the build error `input was in incorrect format` do you know why this might be?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing an int.parse.. s.id is an int (right?), 56 is an int, so the call should literally just be `Array.FindIndex(yourarray, s => s.id == 56)`

Answer (score 1):

What about using `.FindIndex`:

```
var index = members.FindIndex(it => it.name = myName);
```

with `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Answer (score 1):

Use Array.Find() to find the object and Array.IndexOf() to get the index of it.

```cs
Array.IndexOf(members, Array.Find(members, x => x.name == "Name to find"));
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9hy2xwa(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx